# GET method makes my form private (JUST ON SERVER)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I get a mail with a url like that:

http://myDomain/mySite/registration.php?key=41513467593

In registration.php I have at the beginning:

```
if ( ((isset($_GET['key'])) and (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))or ($marker == 1) ){
    // Form
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

When I submit the form, what I do is:

```
// work with variables
header('location: registrationValidation.php');
```

But I see the following error:

http://myDomain/mySite/registration.php?41513467593 it's not found on the server.

It's true, I have *registration.php*, not *registration.php?41513467593*, but when I click on URL with get method I can handle it.

Just one last thing. If I run this on localhost it works, but not on webserver (I'm not the owner of the site, so I can't log phpmyadmin where I guess I could find some error files)

Any advice?

Comment: @YehiaAwad I dont know if you mean if I wrote all the code or if It is all the code. No in both cases, but what I do works perfectly If I remove the first lines where I do the form private

Comment: Have you actually uploaded registration.php to your remote domain?